# exception when stopping jboss server from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, shutdown

I get an exception when I shutdown JBoss server from within Eclipse. I use Jboss 4.2.2GA.

Thank you for your advice

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/Shutdown
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.Shutdown
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: so this is clear. Why I get this exception?

Comment: See @eis's answer. It may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7521), where it has been fixed. JBoss AS4 is quite old, so they might not backport fixes that old. Unless you plan on updating, you just might have to live with it.

Other option is to tweak shutdown.sh script yourself.

However, if the problem only exists in Eclipse and not if you run the script manually yourself, it is a problem in Eclipse-JBoss integration, and in that case updating that should help.